# mocha sidebar is not showing tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I'm developing a very simple typescript project and I added a very tiny test with mocha. I installed mocha sidebar on VS Code and all it's dependencies, but test are not showing in the left panel.

The strange is that when I press debug button, my test run without problem (?)

I want to distribute this package on NPM, and only distribute .js, .d.ts, js.map and d.ts.map files.

I think the problem is in my project.json, but I cannot figure what is it. The source code is [here](https://github.com/vvenegasv/type-exception/tree/develop)

Comment: Vladimir, the problem you are encountering isn't a good match for the Q & A style of Stack Overflow.   The tags you've added are rather broad and not specific to the tool you are having problems with, the Mocha Side Bar add-in for Visual Studeio Code.

Comment: You might have better luck on that tools gitter page:   https://gitter.im/mocha-sidebar/Questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that I notice from your repo is you have `package.json`, test folder and another `src` folder inside `type-exception/src`.

I can run the mocha sidebar plugin successfully.

My solution is to open the project in vscode from the `type-exception/src` folder not `type-exception` folder.

My file structure

[image]

My mocha sidebar

[image]

I also saw that you have correct vscode workspace settings that set mocha files to

```
{
    "mocha.files.glob": "lib/test/**/*.js"
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you tell me what version of VS Code, Typescript, NodeJS and Mocha Sidebar you use? Thanks :)

Comment: VS Code Version 1.28.0, Typescript 2.3.4, NodeJS 8.9.0, Mocha sidebar 0.20.18

Answer (score 4):

The only change I needed was in the VS code workspace settings: Under extensions I pointed the 'mocha glob files'-setting to my test scripts

Answer (score 0):

I had the Testing view showing Jest tests and realised that for Mocha I needed to install another VSCode Extension called "Mocha Test Explorer": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter

Once installed I created/edited a `.vscode/settings.json` file in my project folder and added the following clues to tell Mocha to find my tests under the `tests` folder:

```
{
  "mochaExplorer.files": "tests/**/*.ts"
}
```